# Reading filenames from a structured file to a bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file with a structured list of filenames (`file1.sh, file2.sh, ...`) and would like to read loop the file names inside a bash script.

```
cat /home/flora/logs/9681-T13:17:07.091363777.org
%rec: dynamic

Ptrn: Gnu
File: /home/flora/comint.rc
+ /home/flora/engine.rc
+ /home/flora/playa.rc
+ /home/flora/edva.rc
+ /home/flora/dyna.rc
+ /home/flora/lin.rc
```

Have started with

```
while read -r fl; do
  echo "$fl" | grep -oE '[/].+'
done < "$logfl"
```

But I want to be more specific by matching the `File:` , then continue reading the rest using `+` as a continuation character.

Answer (score 0):

bash doesn't have impose a limit on variables (other than memory).  That said, I would start by processing the list of lines one by one:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read _ f
do
        process "$f"
done
```

where `process` is whatever function you need to implement.

If you want a variables use an array like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read _ f
do
        files+=("$f")
done
```

In either case pass the input file to script with:

```
your_script < /home/flora/logs/27043-T13:09:44.893003954.log
```